# How to place insert shapes to upper level in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Until Excel 2016, the GUI allows easy access to the Insert > Shapes in the top level of the ribbon buttons. But starting Excel 365, the location was moved to Illustrations.

> Insert ribbon group > Shapes

to

> Insert ribbon groups > Illustrations > Shapes

This actually makes my work longer as I usually use the shapes in my Excel a lot. Is there a way to move the Insert Shapes more accessible?

[image: Insert > Illustrations > Shapes]

Comment: @RajeshS not in the version of Excel that I was using. I don't know but there must be a policy in the installation of the software that made it the default. Anyway, I checked your answer and it seems to by the answer I was looking for. Can you move this comment to an actual answer?

Comment: ,, check the post I've shown the entire method will help you & others too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Shapes***, **Pictures** & `others` are parts of **Illustration TAB**, also (in `2013` & `2016`). And If you need direct access to **SHAPES** then do the followings:

*Method 1:*

1. Reach to **File** then **Option** command.
2. From **Customize Ribbons** Tab, check the **Popular Commands** list box.
3. Find **Shape** and *add* it to **Customize/ New Group** (*need to be created earlier*).

*Method 2:*

1. From **Main Tab** select **Insert** then **Illustration**.
2. Hit **Rename** button and from the Poped up dialogue just rename it to **Shapes** or pick any suitable name of your choice.
3. Finish with **Ok**

Comment: Glad to help you @Nassign keep asking ☺